# How to stop and restart a twitter stream with ntwitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, ntwitter

I'm new to node.js so please excuse the simple question. I'm writing something standard: a rest API that goes to twitter using ntwitter and saves stuff on mysql.  What I'm having trouble is disconnecting and connecting back to twitter using ntwitter.

I checked a somewhat similar question to mine but that one is still unanswered: [Restarting nodejs ntwitter twitter stream with different track keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542941/restarting-nodejs-ntwitter-twitter-stream-with-different-track-keywords)

The question is two fold:

1) How to check if the `twit.stream` is alive
2) How to kill it/manually disconnect from twitter

I'm using `destroy` but that does not seem to work. The relevant part of the code is:

```
if (values[0] == 'newStatusAdded') {
  console.log('Need to stop twitter listener');
  //check if twitter stream is running
  if (twit.stream) {
    twit.stream.destroy;
    debugger;
    console.log('Stopped twitter listener');
  }
```

thanks....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a setup somewhere in your code like this:

```
twit.stream('statuses/sample', function(stream) {
  stream.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Save the stream variable from within the callback, for example after `stream.on()`:

```
  twit.currentTwitStream = stream;
```

This is only a suggestion. Perhaps you have a central configuration object which would be a better place for the current stream object. With `currentTwitStream` you can do this:

1. `currentTwitStream.readable` is false after an error or close.
2. `currentTwitStream.destroy()` destroys the stream.

Comment: I know this an old post, but could you provide a more clear example on how you destroy the stream.

Comment: I am sorry, but no, because I don't have the time to test carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this problem too. What eventually worked for me was `stream.stop()`.

`.destroy()`, `.disconnect()` etc brought up a variety of errors such as

> `.destroy` is not defined.